# How do I prevent this regex from matching this pattern?

Tags: regex

How do I stop this regex from matching the first line? I want it to match each line EXCEPT `[keyworddash]`. Basically, if there is a 2nd matching group, then there MUST be a colon.

```
\[keyword(\d?):?(.*)\]
```

```
[keyworddash]
[keyword1]
[keyword2]
[keyword:default]
[keyword2:default]
```

Here is a tester: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93714

Comment: cool tools: regexr.com or regex101.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will exclude the first line by assuming that all lines must either contain a number or a colon

```
\[keyword(?=(\d|:))(\d?):?(.*)\]
```

By using the positive lookahead `(?=(\d|:))` we are making sure that the next character that matches after `keyword` is either a colon or a number, otherwise the match fails.

Comment: Cool I never used forward lookahead before. I also added `\]` to match plain `[keyword]`: `\[keyword(?=(\d|:|\]))(\d?):?(.*)\]`

Comment: That makes sense, but `[keyword]` was not in your match list :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation:

```
\[keyword(\d?)(?:\]|:(.*)\])
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/jI0yH1/1)

So in this case, `(?:\]|:(.*)\])` means that the match either ends with `]` otherwise a colon is required for the second capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the colon optional by itself; make it part of the optional second word:

```
\[keyword\d?(:[a-z]+)?\]
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/jf9eoDfUJn) against your sample input.

This means *keyword optionally followed by a digit optionally followed by a colon and some lowercase letters*.

A simpler regex if the second word can be "anything" is:

```
\[keyword\d?(:.+)?\]
```

Groups aren't required for the expression to match, but if you need to add them in I leave that to you.

Comment: This doesn't match `[keyword2:default]`

Comment: @johan Yes just noticed that - fixed